# Silverlight Hosting Queries

Tags: silverlight, iis, hosting

Can we host an .xap in IIS?
Can we have SL application without web project i.e. html and aspx pages? If yes, then how the silverlight application will be hosted and used?

Comment: +1 To address harsh downvoting.

Comment: I agree, this is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why the harsh down-voting, as it is useful to know how to do *raw Silverlight hosting*, but you can host a XAP file pretty much anywhere. It is the Silverlight plugin that knows what to do with the file (much like the flash knows what to do with flash files hosted anywhere).

As an example these blog entries (my blog) show how to host a silverlight app/XAP for use in Wordpress:
[http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?s=silverlight+in+wordpress](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?s=silverlight%20in%20wordpress)

At its most basic you do need a little bit of Javascript to fire up the Silverlight engine within the browser, which requires some sort of basic HTML page, so not sure why you would want to just (presumably) run the XAP as a download? Perhaps you can clarify?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a browser (and thus an HTML page) to host the XAP using the SilverLight plugin.

However, you can enable the user to download and install your app by making it a [SilverLight Out-of-Browser Application](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/out-of-browser-applications/).

> Silverlight-based applications
>   typically run within Web pages, but
>   you can enable users to install them
>   from the Web and run them outside the
>   browser.